# I frame Popup hidden when hovering in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I add iframe content to wordpress. and there are few pop up for showing some details. when hovering green, yellow, blue dot. like this,
[image]

and when hover on the left , right , bottom points pup up showing half of the content because of i set the overflow hidden. but i want to show them without overflow scrolling. how to show popup front of the iframe. ? can anyone help me.

here is how show left side popup
[image]

css

```
.point-img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 1px;
        min-height: 1px;
    }
    .map-div{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    .map{
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        
    }
    iframe {
        display: block;
        /*iframes are inline by default */
        border: none; 
        /*Reset default border */
        height: 71vh; 
            /*Viewport-relative units */
        width: 100vw;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have access to the iframe code ?

Comment: Cedric Cholley Thank you for reply. Yes I can access.

Comment: OK so I think this is where you need to make the changes. For example when you hover a dot which is on the right of the map the popup should be on the left of the dot. It should be the same with the bottom